# Unable to get the data from DB in a required format using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a rails application where I have 3 models and I'm not able to fetch the data in a required format.

Rails Models

1. Model 1 - *Investigation (id, name, created_at, updated_at)*
2. Model 2 - *Appointment(id, patient_id, investigation_date,....)*
3. Model 3 - *Result (investigation_id, appointment_id, findings)*

Relation b/w models -

*Appointment has_many results*

*Results belongs_to appointment* &
*Results belongs_to investigation*

Table schema snippet

```
create_table "appointments", charset: "utf8mb4", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.bigint "patient_id", null: false
  t.date "investigation_date"
end

create_table "results", charset: "utf8mb4", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.bigint "appointment_id", null: false
  t.bigint "investigation_id", null: false
  t.string "findings"
end

create_table "investigations", charset: "utf8mb4", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "name"
  t.boolean "status", default: true
end
```

Now what I'm looking for is to display the data in a table on the UI in this format -

Table Row1 (fixed)-

Investigation Date (from appointment table),    InvestigationName1(from results table(findings attribute)), InvestigationName2(from results table(findings attribute)), ....

Ex- OUTPUT (on UI)

20-May-2021  100, 120, ....

20-June-2021 90, 120, ....

So far what I have been trying to do is

```
data = {}
result = []
appointments = Appointment.where("patient_id = ? and investigation_date IS NOT NULL", 
params[:p_id]).order("investigation_date desc").last(5)
appointment_id  = appointments.pluck(:id)
results_data    = Result.where(appointment_id: 
appointments.pluck(:id)).includes(:investigation)
appointments.each do |app|
 results_data.each do |data|
  result << data.findings
 end
 data[app.investigation_date.strftime("%d-%b-%Y")] = result
end
```

Help me where I'm doing wrong ?

with the suggestion of @Lukas I was able to fetch data but still there is slight problem in matching that data with the table header attaching the image below

[image: Image data]

In the image the data for the second is not matching up with the header above what I mean is the "okay" belongs to the "E" in the header, "90" belongs to "M" in the header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best I came up with:

```
   investigations > |  .name  |  .name   . .
appointments        |-------------------
      v             |         |
.investigation_date | results | results
.investigation_date | results | results
      .                                  .
      .                                    .
```

Make an array of investigations you want to display. Use it to make the header and then use the same array to get the matching results from each appointment. Then you can pull any information from those results, like, findings.

```
investigations = Investigation.order(:name)

header = ["Date", *investigations.pluck(:name)]

rows = Appointment.includes(results: :investigation).map do |a|
  [
    a.investigation_date,
    *investigations.map do |investigation|
      a.results.select { |r| r.investigation_id == investigation.id }.map(&:findings)
    end
  ]
end
```

I assume you could have more than one investigation on the same day, so this doesn't work and will overwrite existing dates:

```
data[app.investigation_date.strftime("%d-%b-%Y")] = result
```

---

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <% header.each do |th| %>
        <th> <%= th %> </th>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% rows.each do |tr| %>
      <tr>
        <td> <%= tr.shift %> </td>       <!-- date -->
        <% tr.each do |td| %>
          <td> <%= td.join(" ") %> </td> <!-- results -->
        <% end %>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked, while iterating the table instance variable on .erb file I'm doing something like this- <% @results[1].each do |values| %> <tr> <% values.each do |value| %> <td> <% if value.present? %> <% if value.is_a?(Array) %> <%=value.pop%> <% else %> <%=value%> <% end %> <% else %> N/A <% end %> </td> <% end %> </tr> <% end %> 

is it the correct way ?

Comment: @VibhooMishra I've updated the answer a bit. to make it easier to put into a table.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this (It's not very clear what you mean):

```rb
appointments.includes(results: :investigation).map do |app|
  [app.investigation_date.strftime("%d-%b-%Y"), app.results.map(&:findings)] 
end.to_h
```

Comment: it worked a little bit with your answer but still facing a small issue can you please help me again ? I have update the question as well. Basically the data is not matching with the header -
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePoqD.png

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `each_with_object`

```rb
# includes are for eager loading
appointments = Appointment.where("patient_id = ? and investigation_date IS NOT NULL", params[:p_id])
                          .includes(results: :investigation)
                          .order("investigation_date desc")
                          .limit(5)
final_obj = 
  appointments.each_with_object({}) do |app, obj|
    date = app.investigation_date.strftime("%d-%b-%Y")
    obj[date] = app.results.map{|data| data.findings }
  end
```

Note: I have no idea what is `findings` and why you first included `investigation`. If you add model + associations, I might update my solution.

Comment: added model association and table schema snippet as well to the question